# Remove foreign language strings from a list, without loosing english strings with emojis and symbols

Tags: python-3.x

if I have a list containing strings of different languages how can I remove the non english without loosing english strings with emojis and symbols.

```
foreign_strings = ['Instagram', '爱奇艺PPS -《欢乐颂2》电视剧热播', 'Docs To Go™ Free Office Suite', 'Instachat ']
```

Needed result:

```
english_strings = ['Instagram', 'Docs To Go™ Free Office Suite', 'Instachat ']
```

I tried

```
english_strings = []
    
for i in foreign_strings:
    if i.isascii():
        english_strings.append(i)
print(english_strings)
```

This returns:

```
english_strings = ['Instagram']
```

How can I ignore emojis and symbols like the TM

Many thanks

Comment: You should define for yourself what an 'English' string is. Then select the 'English' strings based on those requirements. Setting the requirement to at least 1 ASCII character is not sufficient, since I think the second string also contains ASCII characters (PPS, 2).

Comment: thanks @suitendaal I researched and could not find a way that I understood. I am new to this and was hoping for some guidance. Not sure why someone would mark me down without any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code works with your input :

```
import re
english_check = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z0-9]')
def isEnglish(s):
  list_final = []
  for i in s :
    if english_check.match(i):
        list_final.append(i)

  return(list_final)

foreign_strings = ['Instagram', '爱奇艺PPS -《欢乐颂2》电视剧热播', 'Docs To Go™ Free Office Suite', 'Instachat ']
print(isEnglish(foreign_strings))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried this and it works as desired in my question, however when I apply this to my whole data set it misses some. Could you please explain how you solution works. Many thanks.

Comment: It uses regular expression you can change the pattern as it works.